# Using github packages without personal access token?

Tags: github, github-actions

The project I'm working on currently deploys our private node packages via github packages. Our current workflow is for each developer to create and maintain their own personal access token, and then we use a central account's PAT for automation in AWS.

I was wondering if it's possible to authenticate with github packages without the use of Actions or PAT's?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### As of 2022-07-30

No, it is not possible to use github packages without a personal access token (PAT):

- It is not possible to upload without a PAT (which makes sense as it prevents random people to upload binaries to your package repo);
- It is not possible to download without a PAT (not even publicly available packages can be used);

As early as [2019-10-20](https://web.archive.org/web/20211215173925/https://github.community/t/download-from-github-package-registry-without-authentication/14407), people have requested github to remove PATs as a requirement for mainly downloading public packages.
The idea is that users of libraries should not need to have a github account to access a developer's package.

Sadly, the request for pat-less package downloads was not granted by Github to this day.

If you want a package registry without a hassle, it might be wise to look for other registries, such as MavenCentral or JitPack (not necessarily meant for node packages),
or host a service yourself.

---

I even had to link a cached webpage, as the original question has been removed from Github community along with a bunch of related questions.
Another question on github, stating pat-less access to packages is still on the roadmap for "fall 2021" is [here](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26634).
I could not find what the current status of this feature is.

---

Edit: It is possible to download binaries without a PAT for public repositories using jitpack.io. Jitpack builds the given jar/aar on their servers.
You can add jitpack as a repository to your build system, and use the jitpack-specified URL to reference releases, branches, or specific commits.
Sadly, there is no way to refer to packages (yet).
However, this system allows your users to use your code without needing PATs nor a Github account.

Comment: Are you sure this is still true? Docs indicate public packages can be accessed without auth: https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/configuring-a-packages-access-control-and-visibility

Comment: Interesting! I completely migrated away from github packages due to this authenticate-to-install-public-packages tomfoolery.
According to https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-apache-maven-registry:
`You need an access token to publish, install, and delete private, internal, and public packages.`
It seems github delivers contradicting docs.
If anyone has a project using github packages, please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to offer an alternative.

You may use a Gradle plugin of mine ([magik](https://github.com/elect86/magik), I was exactly in your shoes) to easier the consumption of artifacts from your Github Packages for Gradle clients.

It require you to save your read-only PAT on the repo itself, so that the users don't have to deal with any authentication (apart using the plugin above mentioned)

Comment: Would like to reiterate that this is targeting a node.js project. Gradle isn't involved and would be a major debt to simply avoid managing one token. Would highly advise against this approach.

Comment: Uh, sorry! I didn't realize it was about node.js

Comment: @Djlewald, thinking about it, would you like to cooperate to bring support for node.js?